# Get targeted file's path from .lnk shortcut file (cmd | .bat)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, shortcut

The question was answered by:

```
for /f "delims=" %%c in ('type "C:\a\b.d" ^|find /v "" ^| findstr /I /C:".cmd" /C:".bat"') do (
    set paf="%%c"
    set ext="%%~xc"
)
```

; but i got curious ,is it possible to do same without knowing the target file's possible extension|s?

Comment: sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Are you referring to ´.lnk´ shortcut files ? Otherwise your question is unclear.

Comment: @LotPings, yes.

Comment: @myradio, " ,is it possible to do same without knowing the file's possible extension|s?"

Comment: yes, it is: `wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%filename:\=\\%'" get target /value`

Comment: Llia, you've answered your own question then… _You don't need to know the extension, because it is always the same, `.lnk`, (case insensitive)_.

Comment: @Stephan, no way by using only standard commands?

Comment: Llia, that is a standard command, certainly from Windows XP onwards!

Comment: @Compo maybe, but starting new discussion ,or writing y. or n. answer, whats easier?

Comment: Llia, your comment above makes no sense to me, even after you've attempted to expand upon it by way of edit. Also please note, that there is a minimum requirement of `15` characters for a comment so a `y` or `n` answer would not be allowed!

Comment: @Compo, "15 characters for a comment so a y or n answer would not be allowed!" this is reason why you can't make answer as simple as needed?

Comment: @Stephan, can you please write 1 more example in case when i have {%paf%==|full path to the shortcut|}

Comment: Llia, I haven't made an answer, I responded to your comment because you were incorrect in believing that the `WMIC` command used by @Stephan was not standard, I was correcting you!

Comment: @Compo, i wrote answer to your comment's part that i quoted

Comment: I gave you the answer to this a few days back. Why did you create a new user.

Comment: @Squashman, i know, the question was deleted and i didn't copied the code before, thats why had to create new one, thankss for the accepted answer belongs to you too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "paf=C:\Users\Stephan\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\notepad.lnk"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%paf:\=\\%'" get target /value') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%b in ("%%~a") do set ext=%%~xb
)
echo target extension: %ext%
```

(`wmic` expects a full path to the file and doubled `/`)

(Credit goes to Squashman, who used this method in an answer to a meanwhile [deleted quesition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50805330/2152082))

Comment: I am upvoting this because I'm impressed you could actually understand the question.

Comment: @myradio: there was a quite similar question recently, which helped understanding it. (had a hard time to find it again, 'cause it was deleted)

Comment: @myradio, we answered this same question for the user a couple of days ago and then they either deleted their question or a moderator did.  The code in his initial question was one of the answers and the other answer was this WMIC option that I had posted.  The user then gave me a gazillion excuses on why they didn't want to use the WMIC option but have now seemed to like it better than the more brute force method.

Comment: I have been working on something like this. Instead of "paf", I used even one more for loop, so 3 loops-nested. The batchfile is set in a directory where I want to inspect a thousand shortcuts, say. And in all these shortcuts, the path is now destroyed, because the 'path' in the shortcuts was changed (a sub-directory was renamed for example). I want to just read the 'path' and change it to read the correct internal path of each shortcut. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to that already answered.

If you want the locations of any shortcuts to batch files on your `C:` drive:

```bat
WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where "Drive='C:' And Target Like '%.cmd' Or Target Like '%.bat'" Get Name 2>Nul|FindStr "\.lnk\>"
```

From a batch file you'll need to double up the percent characters, `%`

```bat
@WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where "Drive='C:' And Target Like '%%.cmd' Or Target Like '%%.bat'" Get Name 2>Nul|FindStr "\.lnk\>"
```

If you want the locations of all shortcuts on your `D:` drive:

```bat
WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where "Drive='D:'" Get Name 2>Nul|FindStr "\.lnk\>"
```

---

As a final example to find out the extensions of the targets of each shortcut on your `C:` drive.

From the command prompt:

```bat
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %A In ('WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where "Drive='C:'" Get Target 2^>Nul') Do @For %B In (%~xA) Do @Echo %B
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_ShortcutFile Where "Drive='C:'" Get Target 2^>Nul') Do @For %%B In (%%~xA) Do @Echo %%B
```